# I want to return true when my sprite is touched

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i want to return true to my method touch, when the sprite is touched (also with the finger) how can I make?

```
public class SkipButton extends RectangleButton
{   

    protected TextureAtlas atlasTexture;

    protected Sprite sprite; 

    protected SpriteBatch batch ;


    public SkipButton(Vector2 coordinates, float width, float height) 
    {
        super(coordinates, width, height);
        atlasTexture = Assets.manager.get(Constants.INTERFACE_ATLAS_PATH,         
        TextureAtlas.class);
        sprite = new Sprite(atlasTexture.findRegion("skip_big"));

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }

    public boolean touch()
    {
       ...........
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Libgdx has a great Button class which has included a `boolean isPressed()` which will do what you want. You can still make a public method that returns the result of isPressed if you want your button to be private.

```
atlasTexture = Assets.manager.get(Constants.INTERFACE_ATLAS_PATH,         
    TextureAtlas.class);
Drawable drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(atlasTexture.findRegion("skip_big"));
button = new Button(drawable);
stage.addActor(button);

public boolean touch() {
    return button.isPressed();
}
```

Comment: I found a great example showing the basics of scene2d. http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx

Comment: Button already has an [`isPressed()`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html#isPressed--) method

Comment: Oh yeah that is true, this can be even more simplified. Editing it now.